# Groovy source file compilation in Intellij

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

I have a `grails 2.4.4` project on IntelliJ with `groovy` source files under `grails-app\groovy` . Unfortunately `IntelliJ` keeps showing me compilation error messages whenever I use any class under the `groovy` package. Though actually there is no error and app is compiling and runs just fine, just that I see my `grails controllers/services` filled up red marks with messages `cannot resolve symbol`. I am sure this has got to do with some settings on `IntelliJ` but cant understand why it does not come pre-loaded with `grails intellij plugin`.

Comment: If you go to your module settings and then click the Sources tab, does src/groovy show up as a blue folder? If it doesn't, click the groovy folder and then click Sources just above the tree. Grails won't care about that, but IntelliJ will.

Comment: Is there any reason, why you use `grails-app/groovy` as a source folder insted of `src/groovy` ? With this setting intellij has no problem, because it is already configured as a source folder.

Comment: @Gregg thanks for your helpful comment. I got it now.

Comment: @Gregg can you put your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to your module settings and then click the Sources tab, does src/groovy show up as a blue folder? If it doesn't, click the groovy folder and then click Sources just above the tree. Grails won't care about that, but IntelliJ will

Comment: For those looking for the Sources option, I found it in my version of IntelliJ under Project Structure -> Modules.